# How to wire Swing DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE to menu bar option

Tags: java, swing

So I want to have an "Exit" option on my menubar, NP. The JFrame already has the DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE in it's setDefaultCloseOperation method. I've looked around and have yet to find what I believe is a good example... What's a good or right way? A little help please!

As Always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [ExitAction](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) to your Exit menu item. It will react just like the user clicke the "close" button on the frame. The rest of the article really isn't applicable to your requirement.

Comment: I followed the example you pointed to (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).  It's working as I'd like and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do `someFrame.dispose ()`